# Regex in python to remove the isolated occurence of a character and number many times

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, regex-negation, regex-greedy

data = I have a data like **"various people in our 96 35 lab will a a a a prepare 43 65 66 43liter or so of lb add kanamycin"**

**I want to print it like "various people in our lab will prepare 43liter or so of lb add kanamycin"**

Please Note: 43liter should not be removed. as it has the text after the number and hence not isolated.

I tried using the following way:-

```
data = re.sub('\s[a-z]\s', ' ', data)
data = re.sub('\s[a-z]\s', ' ', data)
data = re.sub('\s[a-z]\s', ' ', data)
data = re.sub('\s[a-z]\s', ' ', data)
```

to remove 4 isolated 'a' I have to do the same task 4 times. Same goes with isolated numbers too.

**Is there a better regex version can be done for the same??**

Comment: Please provide a set of rules that describe the text you wish to remove

Comment: all the isolated characters (e.g. a, i ) and pure numbers(e.g. 23, 95) i want to remove. Problem is i tried with characters first, but my regex in one pass removes only one occurrence of 'a' and rest a remain unchanged. I want to remove all such isolated 'a' occurence in one pass

Comment: There is a more precise way to do this [`\b(?:\d+\b\s|([a-z]+\s+)\1+)`](https://regex101.com/r/M40Lie/2)

Answer (score 2):

- I would use `\b` (word boundary) to replace only digits that are a "word" (not attached to other letters). Searching for spaces before/after make you miss matches if strings to be removed are at the start/end of the string.
- I would use the same `\b` to isolate single letters (given your attempt, you want to remove all single letters)

After replacement, there would be more than 1 space, so I consume it after the match. Code:

```
import re

s = "various people in our 96 35 lab will a a a a prepare 43 65 66 43liter or so of lb add kanamycin"

print(re.sub(r"\b\d+\b *|\b[a-z]\b *","",s))
```

result:

```
various people in our lab will prepare 43liter or so of lb add kanamycin
```

we can factorize the regex further on with a *group* since start & end are the same:

```
print(re.sub(r"\b(\d+|[a-z])\b *","",s))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have it like:

```
\b(?:\d+|[a-z])\b\s+
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/cTvkaz/2).

---

In `Python` this is:

```
import re

string = "various people in our 96 35 lab will a a a a prepare 43 65 66 43liter or so of lb add kanamycin"
rx = re.compile(r'\b(?:\d+|[a-z])\b\s+')

new_string = rx.sub('', string)
print(new_string)
# various people in our lab will prepare 43liter or so of lb add kanamycin
```